# Background image size for tablets

Tags: android, drawable

I am creating an app with an full screen background image. I read a lot and made different images for different resolutions with the recommended pixel size and provide it in different drawable folders:

```
xxxhdpi: 1440x2560 px
xxhdpi: 1080x1920 px
xhdpi: 768*1280 px
hdpi: 480x800 px
mdpi: 320x480 px
ldpi: 240x320 px
```

I tested it on different phones and all look great.

Now my Problem: it doesnt't look great on tablets... and its logical. Samsung Galaxy tab 10 for example is 800*1280 mdpi.

So what is the solution? different folders for phones and tablets (7" and 10")? are there recommended sizes in pixels like there are for phones? how do others do this?

Thanks a lot for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using drawables for background, and the image you added in the drawable surpass the dimensions from the list you supplied, it will be scaled by default (afaik).

Some things you have to keep in mind :
1) This applies both landscape and portrait. 
2) If you are downloading the images from the web for creating the background drawable via code, you can handle the desired size by processing that image directly from the backend. Also, with libraries like Glide or Picasso, you can manage the resize thing.

Best regards,